# Assigning value to pointer's element causing programming to crash

Tags: c++, pointers

Can someone help me understand why the following doesn't work:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

const uint16_t SINGLE_FRAME_BUFFER_SIZE = 15000;
const uint8_t BUFFER_SIZE = 4;

struct Buffer *data_buffer;

struct Frame
{
    uint8_t video_data[SINGLE_FRAME_BUFFER_SIZE];
    uint16_t video_data_size;
};

struct Buffer
{
    uint8_t item_pointer;
    struct Frame *items;
};

int main()
{
    data_buffer = (struct Buffer *)malloc(sizeof(struct Buffer));
    data_buffer->items = (struct Frame *)malloc(sizeof *data_buffer->items * BUFFER_SIZE);
    data_buffer->item_pointer = 0;

    if (data_buffer == NULL or data_buffer->items == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // This line causes a crash
    struct Frame *single_frame = &data_buffer->items[data_buffer->item_pointer];
    single_frame->video_data_size = 2;
    // printf("%d\n", single_frame->video_data_size);
}
```

But this doesn't cause it to crash

```c
    struct Frame single_frame = data_buffer->items[data_buffer->item_pointer];
    single_frame.video_data_size = 2;
```

From my understanding, in the first example, I am getting a pointer to the memory address of the Frame object. Then, I am accessing its attribute which is not a pointer, and assign it a value.

Also, I'm doing this on an embedded system. So the only exception I receive is a StoreProhibited

Edit:

Sorry, added more info to the example to make it clear. This is running on Arduino in PlatformIO (C++). For some reason,  that line is causing Freetos to throw a `StoreProbihited` error, although it works fine compiling it alone.

Comment: What is `SINGLE_FRAME_BUFFER_SIZE` and `BUFFER_SIZE`? Please give complete code. One thing to check is the `single_frame` address in the two cases. Maybe in the crashing case the compiler is producing unaligned accesses. Otherwise can't see any other obvious issue.

Comment: Looks fine to me (fixing obvious typos and filling in missing bits), and ASAN/valgrind don't complain: https://godbolt.org/z/rnKbWfYYd  Possibly something platform-specific?  `malloc` on embedded platforms often has serious limitations or caveats.  Your "doesn't crash" version doesn't write to the allocated memory at all (though it does read its uninitialized contents, which is not great).  Tell us about your platform and build/run process.

Comment: `data_buffer == NULL or data_buffer->items == NULL` it is not C for sure. Your code does not crash - it simply does not compile

Comment: @user17732522  `return;` _will_ produce a warning here because `main` returns `int`. But, `return;` _is_ valid C (in a function returning `void` as in: `void foo(void) { return; }`).

Comment: Now is probably a good time to set up some better debugging tools, so that you can not only find out that there *was* an exception, but also which instruction caused it, which address it tried to access, and what was contained in registers/memory at the time.

Comment: @0___________ It is with `#include<iso646.h>`.

Comment: @CraigEstey Yes, sure, I thought that "_in this context_" would be understood implicitly.

Comment: @user17732522, I added more details. Maybe it's something else in my environment because when I compile it by itself it doesn't through an error...

Comment: @Movieboy It is hard to tell then. One thing that isn't correct in the code is that you check the return value from the first `malloc` too late. If it is a null pointer you have UB.

Comment: Arduino Uno has 32K of memory. You are trying to allocate about 60K.